# How does the Commodore 64 address more than 64 kilobytes of memory?

Tags: commodore-64, memory-layout

So, the Commodore 64 has two special registers in locations $00 and $01. By writing to these registers, you can somehow turn on and off the ROMs and other things. The thing that I am not understanding is why there is a direction register at location $00.

So if you write a 1 or 0 to the first bit in location $01, somehow this controls whether you can read from Commodore BASIC ROM or from RAM at the same addresses (in the literature this is apparently known as the `LORAM` signal). And I'm interested in knowing what happens if you write a particular value to the same bit in location $00. Does that mean that `LORAM` is now an input? Can you use this to test if BASIC is on?

Comment: The question in the title and the questions in the body do not seem to match up. Can you tighten this up, and ask one primary question per post, please?

Comment: I don't mind changing it of course, but because I am asking about the mechanism that allows for the system to address more than 64 kilobytes. So "How does that work" seems fine to me, so what would you suggest for a title for this question?

Comment: You ask 'how does it do it', then say how it does it, and ask a final specific question about how the mechanism can be used. The problem with this approach is that your final question about reading this register risks getting lost in the noise.   Strictly, your title does not ask `how does it work`, I think it effectively asks `what is it` (where `it` is the mechanism for accessing memory), and that feels slightly awkward to read (in UK English at least).

Comment: Answer to title: is Banking. C64 consists of different banks that points to different areas in memory..

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The [6510 CPU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MOS_Technology_6510) used in the Commodore 64 has an additional built-in [general purpose I/O port](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General-purpose_input/output) compared to the original [6502 CPU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MOS_Technology_6502). Address $0000 controls the direction for each of the bits of this I/O port, address $0001 can be used to read the voltage level of the corresponding pin for inputs, or set the voltage level of this pin for output.

In the Commodore 64, the pins for the lowest three bits of this port are connected to a [PLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programmable_logic_array), where they control the address space layout. All three lines are also pulled up to +5V via resistors. So if you'd change the direction of any of these port bits from `output` to `input`, the line would just be held at +5V, you could read a `1` in the corresponding position at address $0001, and the PLA would behave like a `1` is output to it.

Therefore this setting serves no purpose, it's the same as if you had kept the direction to `output` and wrote a `1` into the data register. In particular it can't be used to test anything.

(I'll assume that this is your real question, and you are not asking about details how the Commodore 64 uses those 3 signals to control the address space layout, i.e. ROM/RAM. If you need those details, there's a table e.g. [here](https://www.c64-wiki.com/index.php/Bank_Switching).)

Comment: I've heard that reading $0000 gives the current input/output direction settings and reading $0001 will give the current setting for pins configured as outputs (and the input value on pins configured as inputs, of course).  Is that correct?

Comment: @GeorgePhillips: That would be the usual way to handle GPIO registers if you can actually read the registers (sometimes you can't). The 6510 data sheet doesn't say if you can read them, but it would be easy to find out using an actual 6510.

Comment: Reading $00 and $01 was suggested in this thread:  http://www.lemon64.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=53259  Was hoping to get a more reliable confirmation.

Comment: @GeorgePhillips: If INC is actually used in existing programs to toggle the lowest bit on both addresses, then yes, you can read both registers. I don't own a C64, but anyone who owns one should be able to easily check, if that is not enough confirmation.

Comment: I wonder why the 6510 implemented the I/O using addresses 0 and 1 rather than using some otherwise unused opcodes [e.g. after fetching opcode $C2, the 6502 will fetch and ignore a second byte; hardware to watch for opcode $C2 could then capture that byte].

Comment: @supercat - looking at [these photos of an 8500 die](http://www.revengineer.de/8500/8500_decapped.jpg) (which is a 6510 made in a slightly different process) versus [an original 6502D](http://visual6502.org/images/6502/6502_top_op10x_BF_4677.png) I don't think they changed the die layout beyond absolutely minimal changes.  They cut out the original external interfacing circuits and put a new set surrounding the core (mostly along the right hand edge, which makes sense as that's where the P0...P5 pins connect), but for the most part the core itself is untouched.  Including unused areas where...

Comment: ... interface circuits or connection points originally intruded into the mostly rectangular space occupied by the processor core itself, but which were not as useful for the 6510 layout so ended up being unused..

Comment: As to monitoring for a specific opcode, (1) it would be fairly hard without support from the core itself for the extra hardware to distinguish opcode fetches from other memory accesses - the only chips that I'm aware of that did this kind of thing were the Intel 8087 and 8089 coprocessors and the 8086 had been specifically designed from the beginning to allow for it, and (2) I'm not entirely convinced that at the point this was designed, anyone actually *knew* for sure what the undocumented opcodes did.  Their functions are effectively arbitrary, and identifying them isn't easy.

Comment: The 6502 has an output that marks instruction fetches.  Hardware to replace a fetched opcode with $EA if it matches $Fx while feeding the bottom 4 bits to an addressable latch would be fairly straightforward.

Comment: Some processors like the 8086 require specialized logic for instruction synchronization because instruction prefetches can be interleaved with other operations, but the 6502 always performs an instruction fetch after the last access associated with the previous instruction.

Comment: @GeorgePhillips Yes, you can indeed read the 6810 data direction register. Try a `PRINT PEEK(0)` on any C64 or emulator and you will get back `47`, or `%101111` in binary. Bit 4 is used for the `CASS SENSE` line, which you read to see if someone has pressed "Play" (or another button) on the Datasette. And next time, just post this as a question. :-)

Answer (score 17):

The C64 BASIC ROM lives at $A000, the KERNEL ROM lives at $E000, but these ROMs also have RAM wired in 'parallel'  Under normal operation this RAM is unused but you can use the LORAM/HIRAM bits to enable or disable the ROMS and switch in the equivalent RAM memory.

One fun trick is to write a quick basic program to PEEK all the addresses from $A000 to $FFFF and POKE them back into the same address.  You can't write to ROM, so what the 64 will do is basically copy the PEEKed value from ROM and put it into the same address in RAM.  You then flip the LORAM/HIRAM bits to 'turn off the ROM' and use the RAM exclusively and you have a C64 with 'modifiable' roms.  You can add new commands to the BASIC interpreter, or tweak your ROMs.  But the copy in RAM is volatile and will go away when the power gets turned off.

You can use the LORAM bit to determine if the C64 is reading addresses $A000-$BFFF from ROM or from RAM, obviously if it reports ROM then BASIC is available.

Many programs take over the entire C64 by turning off the ROMS and using the available RAM for their own program code (or resources).

Dig up a copy of **Mapping the C64 by Compute!** for EVERYTHING you ever wanted to know about the C64 memory map.

Comment: You can download [_Mapping the C64_ from The Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/Compute_s_Mapping_the_Commodore_64). (As I understand it, they only archive books that are in the public domain.)

Comment: That tip about writes to addresses where ROM is mapped passing through to RAM is brilliant!